# How to use predict for nlp in Tensorflow-keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have bit of problem when predicting named entity recognition set.
After i trained and tested all went good. Now i want to test on raw data like strings .

I tried to use

```
model.predict(['Elon musk is good guy , he owns spacex, tesla.'])
```

but it throws erorr,

```
UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
     [[node functional_29/Cast (defined at <ipython-input-210-e13dae4a124d>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_223088]

Function call stack:
predict_function
```

I have token2index and

tag2index , dictionaries built from trained set. I tried to convert it and use  these but predicted shows 0 on all ,

```
word = ['Elon musk is good guy , he owns spacex, tesla.']
word_index = [[token2idx[word] for word in word]]
X = pad_sequences(sequences=word_index, maxlen=7, padding='post')
predicted = np.argmax(model.predict(X), axis=-1) 
print(predicted)
```

gives
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
which is not true. Even tried a snippet sentence of x_train[0] but it throws like this.
Thanks you for helping.

Comment: Please clarify, which error is thrown

Comment: what does `model.predict(X)` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to predict words, right?

Then you should split your words:

```
sentence = 'Elon musk is good guy , he owns spacex, tesla.'
word_index = [[token2idx[word] for word in sentence.split(' ')]]
X = pad_sequences(sequences=word_index, maxlen=7, padding='post')
predicted = np.argmax(model.predict(X), axis=-1) 
print(predicted)
```

**Update**

As the discussion showed, the issue was in the model having a high accuracy during learning, but the output was always zero.

Since your y-class sizes are not even distributed, the models learns, that improving the prediction for one class will improve the accuracy very fast very quickly. So your y data is something like this: `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,3,0]`. With three classes : `0,1,3` the model learns quickly to predict zeros well, since that increases the accuracy the most. **But**

the model does **only** learn to predict 0, which already gives it a high accuracy. E.G. when one sequence contains of 20 words, so 20 y values and 19 are 0, the model will reach an accuracy of **95%** by just predicting 0 all the time. So a high accuracy is in that case no measure for the quality of the model, since for increasing the performance of the model for all classes, a jump from 95% to 98% does improve the model way more than the jump from 50% to 95%.

Comment: what actually do you want to predict?

Comment: Here is my full code https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jVIfVQX6K5oY6byLKcJNAf8gsR-ukHEM?usp=sharing  .  Thanks for you help

Comment: I cannot look at the whole code unfortunately, but since your model has a high accuracy, it thinks its predicting the right thing, therefore your output is as expected. Have a look at your y values, the preprocessing might be the cause

Comment: Have a look at what y=0 is

Comment: Then your model might be well learning to predict zeros. So when you input a sentence with 20 words, and only one words y is not zero, the model will reach an accuracy of 95%, by just predicting 0 all the time. So either train it way longer, or have a look at your model structure, becuase the 96% accuracy of your model does as I stated, do not say very much

Comment: I dont understand your comment, can you explain that one more?